# What's the difference between NotSupportedException and NotImplementedException?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

My classes that implements an interface, I've got to **throw an exception if the class doesn't support** values from parent class (done by setting the get property to false/true), so why should I use `NotSupportedException`, but not `NotImplementedException`?

When should I use `NotImplementedException` then? learn.microsoft.com say that it's always better to use NotSupportedException, is it true?

I've found sth like that: https://blog.excastle.com/2004/10/15/notimplementedexception-vs-notsupportedexception/, but it was written in 2004, I think many changed after that. Also, it is written in quite complicated way.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"Not Implemented" implies that it could be implemented it in the future. "Not Supported" makes no such implication as to whether you may implement it or if it even can be implemented.

`NotImplementedException` is generally used during development as a way to flag to yourself (or Testers, or any other developers) that some aspect hasn't been implemented yet but it is intended to be implemented. You wouldn't normally include this exception in a formal release.